# Why does torch.compile need to use g++?

Tags: python, c++, pytorch, g++

I was trying to use the `compile` feature that was introduced with Pytorch 2 and had trouble getting it to work. After much debugging, I realised that the problem came from g++: it was using an incorrect version on my machine that didn't support C++17. Patching it by setting the `cpp.cxx` config option to the correct path was sufficient to fix this up.

Although the problem is solved, I'd still like to understand this better. From the docs I get that at first torch dynamo will jit-compile it into an fx-graph intermediate representation. However, I am struggling to understand how g++ comes into this: if it can only convert C++ to machine code, where does its C++ input come from? Does the torch inductor generate C++ code from the intermediate representation, which can then be executed?

Comment: "Does torch inductor generate C++ code from the intermediate representation" yes it does exactly that.